# How to enter in TWRP/recover on Huawei P9 lite with keys?

Tags: twrp, huawei

I have a p9 lite Huawei.
I can boot into twrp with this command

```
adb reboot recovery
```

But without adb, I cannot enter in recovery mode.
If I push <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd>, it goes into bootloader (I can see a green droid logo).
If I push <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd>, it opens the EMUI recovery.
How to get recovery mode with twrp?Is possible with fastboot?
I have installed the twrp with

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
```

Comment: Are you sure that TWRP was/is installed properly? Because it seems that you have 2 recoveries.

Comment: I have installed with fastboot flash recovery twrp.img

Comment: Does it make a difference when usb cable is connected? you can try 'fastboot oem reboot-recovery' or 'fastboot oem reboot recovery' or 'fastboot boot twrp.img' or you can try to flash twrp on erecovery (may brick your device) ask in the forum where you downloaded TWRP does really nobody know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround to enter in recovery.

```
a)Turn off device
b)Push power+VolumeDown
c)We enter in bootloader mode, with volumeup key we select the "recovery" and press power
d)Device reboot to twrp
```

Comment: thats so simple i used this often that i didn't consider you haven't tried that before and completely forgot about it

Answer (score 1):

The basic process of installing TWRP on every phone is to boot into TWRP itself first so TWRP could overwite the recovery partition and replace the stock Android recovery with TWRP itself.

Step 1:
Boot into bootloader / fastboot mode

Step 2:
Make sure that your device's boot loader is unlocked. If not, please follow this tutorial on forum.xda-developers.com by user Mandrigan. https://forum.xda-developers.com/huawei-p9lite/how-to/guide-unlock-bootloader-twrp-root-t3405701

Step 3:
Boot into fastboot mode again. Type in the command
`fastboot flash xxxxx.img`

Where xxxxx.img is your TWRP image file name.

Step 4:
Immediately boot into recovery (make sure you don't boot into Android!!!)

Step 5:
While in TWRP, Press "Mount" and tick on "System" box. Then go to "Advanced" --> "File Manager" find a folder with the name "system". Go into that folder and scroll down until you find a file with something like "recovery-from-boot.xxx". Press on the file name and press on "Rename" and add ".bak" at the end of the file name and it should look like this "recovery-from-boot.xxx.bak"

Step 6:
It is recommended to flash either SuperSU or Magisk so TWRP stays and it doesn't get overwritten by stock Android recovery.

Installation is done and you should have TWRP as your permanent recovery!!

Comment: the question is about key combo not how to flash recovery. besides this the fastboot command you stated is incorrect, and bootloader can't be unlocked (not from huawei, at least. they won't provide unlock codes)